# How to wrap javafx 8 GUI around my Model program

Tags: java, css, javafx, fxml

I'm new to JavaFx 8 and I'm Absolutely lovin it. I've built my GUI and was able to get all my basic functionality  running like it's supposed to. Now as an experiment I have A chunk of code I want to run inside of this GUI but I'm not exactly sure if I should toss it in my (Controller) class and replace `System.out.println()` with `textArea.setText()` whenever I need to print to text Area -> screen.or keep it in the (Model).

here is the code I want to place inside the program...

```
    Quick_SortFXController theSort = new Quick_SortFXController(10);

    theSort.generateRandomArray();

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Quick_SortFX.theArray));

    theSort.quickSort(0, 9);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Quick_SortFX.theArray));


}

Quick_SortFXController(int newArraySize) {

    arraySize = newArraySize;

    theArray = new int[arraySize];

    generateRandomArray();

}

public void quickSort(int left, int right) {

    if (right - left <= 0)
        return; // Everything is sorted

    else {

        // It doesn't matter what the pivot is, but it must
        // be a value in the array

        int pivot = theArray[right];

        System.out.println("Value in right " + theArray[right]
                + " is made the pivot");

        System.out.println("left = " + left + " right= " + right
                + " pivot= " + pivot + " sent to be partitioned");

        int pivotLocation = partitionArray(left, right, pivot);

        System.out.println("Value in left " + theArray[left]
                + " is made the pivot");

        quickSort(left, pivotLocation - 1); // Sorts the left side

        quickSort(pivotLocation + 1, right);

    }

}


public int partitionArray(int left, int right, int pivot) {

    int leftPointer = left - 1;

    int rightPointer = right;

    while (true) {

        while (theArray[++leftPointer] < pivot)
            ;

        printHorzArray(leftPointer, rightPointer);

        System.out.println(theArray[leftPointer] + " in index "
                + leftPointer + " is bigger than the pivot value " + pivot);

        while (rightPointer > 0 && theArray[--rightPointer] > pivot)
            ;

        printHorzArray(leftPointer, rightPointer);

        System.out.println(theArray[rightPointer] + " in index "
                + rightPointer + " is smaller than the pivot value "
                + pivot);

        printHorzArray(leftPointer, rightPointer);

        if (leftPointer >= rightPointer) {

            System.out.println("left is >= right so start again");

            break;

        }

        else {

            swapValues(leftPointer, rightPointer);

            System.out.println(theArray[leftPointer] + " was swapped for "
                    + theArray[rightPointer]);

        }

    }
            swapValues(leftPointer, right);

    return leftPointer;

}
public void swapValues(int indexOne, int indexTwo) {

    int temp = theArray[indexOne];
    theArray[indexOne] = theArray[indexTwo];
    theArray[indexTwo] = temp;

}

public void generateRandomArray() {

    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {

        // Generate a random array with values between
        // 10 and 59

        theArray[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 50) + 10;

    }

}

static void printHorzArray(int i, int j) {

    for (int n = 0; n < 61; n++)
        System.out.print("-");

    System.out.println();

    for (int n = 0; n < arraySize; n++) {

        System.out.format("| %2s " + " ", n);

    }

    System.out.println("|");

    for (int n = 0; n < 61; n++)
        System.out.print("-");

    System.out.println();

    for (int n = 0; n < arraySize; n++) {

        System.out.print(String.format("| %2s " + " ", theArray[n]));

    }

    System.out.println("|");

    for (int n = 0; n < 61; n++)
        System.out.print("-");

    System.out.println();

    if (i != -1) {

        // Number of spaces to put before the F

        int spacesBeforeFront = 6 * (i + 1) - 5;

        for (int k = 0; k < spacesBeforeFront; k++)
            System.out.print(" ");

        System.out.print("L" + i);

        // Number of spaces to put before the R

        int spacesBeforeRear = 5 * (j + 1) - spacesBeforeFront;

        for (int l = 0; l < spacesBeforeRear; l++)
            System.out.print(" ");

        System.out.print("R" + j);

        System.out.print("\n");

    }
```

whats the best way to make this happen. I just need to see it done once and then it's on after that...

thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

What about a third approach?

You could define a [Service](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html) which does the QuickSort computing (in a background thread) and tells your controller when the job is done. And your controller only has to update the view with the result. Thus, your logic is decoupled from the rest of the application code (and you avoid freezing the UI if the sorting takes a long time).

You have an example in the tutorial [Concurrency in JavaFx](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm) from Oracle. The part of the code responsible for instantiating, giving the "success callback" and starting the computing should go to the controller:

```
FirstLineService service = new FirstLineService();
service.setUrl("http://google.com");
service.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(WorkerStateEvent t) {
        System.out.println("done:" + t.getSource().getValue());
    }
});

service.start();
```

Here the service is getting the first line of a HTTP response, but you can define your own in the same way. Enjoy JavaFx.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Comment: OK I'm Kinda getting this and I've been looking for a video tutorial on the matter.

Comment: I'm confusing the hell outa myself. now where in this code do I do my modifications with the above code or better yet where can i find a video tut with a brief demonstration?